# How can I toggle between two DataTables on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, datatables

I have two SharePont lists and the data needs to be rendered on a page using [datatables](https://datatables.net/).  I also have two radio buttoons and each one represents a different datatable that will be rendered to the same page.  When I click on either one, it should render the associated datatable on the page with the ability to toggle back and forth between the two tables.  I was able to successfully get the tables to display and I was able to toggle.  The problem I'm having is that every time I toggle, my header gets rendered just as many times. See below for an example
[image]

In my code, I thought I could resolve the problem by using the remove() method to remove the node from the DOM but that had consequences of its own due other code dependent on the removed node.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.7/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.7/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div>Choose report</div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:25px">
        big Audits: <input type="radio" id="bigAudits" name="Audits" value="big Audits" onclick="ajaxCall(this)" /><br />
        small Audits: <input type="radio" id="smallAudits" name="Audits" value="small Audits" onclick="ajaxCall(this)" />
    </div>
    
    <table id="bigReport" class="display" style="width:100%;display:none" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Report #</th>
                <th>OOO</th>
                <th>RRR</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>big Code</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Modify Date</th>
                <th>Close Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table id="smallReport" class="display" style="width:100%;display:none" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Report #</th>
                <th>OOO</th>
                <th>RRR</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>big Code</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Modify Date</th>
                <th>Close Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here's the javaScript:

```
function ajaxCall(listName){
    if (listName.value === 'big Audits'){
        if (document.getElementById("smallReport_wrapper") !== null){
            document.getElementById("smallReport_wrapper").style.display = "none"
        }
        document.getElementById("bigReport").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("smallReport").style.display = "none";
    }else{
        
        document.getElementById("smallReport").style.display = "block";
        if (document.getElementById("bigReport_wrapper") !== null){
            document.getElementById("bigReport_wrapper").style.display = "none"
            //document.getElementById("bigReport").remove();
        }
        document.getElementById("bigReport").style.display = "none";
    }
    
  $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+ listName.value + "')/items",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"   
    },
    success:dosomething,
    error:dosomethingelse
  })    

}

function dosomething(data){
alert("in data");
    var radioValue = "";
    
    if (document.querySelector("#bigAudits").checked){
        radioValue = "bigReport"
    }else{
        alert(radioValue);
        radioValue = "smallReport" 
    }

    data = data.d.results;
    var html = "";
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
    //console.log(index+"-"+value);
        html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td size='10'><a href='edit.aspx?id=" + value.ID + "'>edit</a></td>";
            html += "<td>" + value.reportNum + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + value.OOO + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + value.RRR + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + value.Subject + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + value.big_code + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + value.StartDate + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + value.modifydate + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + value.modifydate + "</td>";
        html +="</tr>";
    })
    $('#'+radioValue+'  tbody').append(html);
    
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#'+radioValue+'  thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#'+radioValue+' thead' );
    $('#'+radioValue+' thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $(this).text();
        if (i===0){ //don't need the textbox for the 'Edit' column
            $(this).html( ' ' );
        }else{
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" size="10" style="background-color:#eeeeee" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        }
        
 
        $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
 
    var table = $('#'+radioValue).DataTable( {
        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        destroy:true
    } );
}

function dosomethingelse(){
alert("error");
 console.log("dosomethingelse");
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.  I have been struggling with this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it always has duplicate headers is caused by below code:

[image]

Each click will make a copy of the existing headers. And you may also take a reference of this [code](https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/jssharing/2tables.html).

BR

Comment: apologies for the late response.  The  code worked perfectly.  I understood what you did except this part.   ```            if (typeof table != "undefined") {
                table.clear();
                table.destroy();
            }```

where is ```table``` coming from?